# how to print an elements of Future Map dynamic, dynamic

Tags: android, flutter, list, dart, future

I am looking to print the elements of a Future Map, I obtain these elements through an API result, and I can read the result with a then, but I cannot use this result to display it on the screen and use its elements outside of the then, as I use the elements that I get in the then to make the structure per screen with each returned element.

```
`class _PaginaDetalleScreenState extends State<PaginaDetalleScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Future<Map<dynamic, dynamic>> progs =
        login().detalles(widget.clave, widget.sucursal, widget.folio);
    // progs.then((value) => print(value['ocs'][0][2]));

    print(progs[0]); // how to print each element

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xff3c4854),
        title: const Text('Detalles Pedido'),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: null,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return;
          }),
    );
  }
}`
```

I tried to pass the map to a list to access each data and be able to display it individually on the screen, I also tried to save the elements with a cycle in another variable to change its structure, however I still get the same result, a dynamic future map dynamic.

Comment: If you have the future, you don't have the value yet.  If you're in build() you can't wait, so you use something like FutureBuilder to show a substitute widget in the meanwhile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al hacer una petición para consumir una API, estamos en espera de una respuesta, no precisamente instantánea, si no que puede demorar dependiendo varios factores de la propia conexión. Para esto se utiliza la programación asíncrona, lo que hay que hacer es una función asíncrona que espera la respuesta mientras lo demás se construye, ya con un respuesta clara, entonces mostramos la respuesta, mediante gestión de estados. De esta forma solucione el problema...

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart'; // Paquete necesario para la petición a internet.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Opcion1 extends StatefulWidget {

  const Opcion1({super.key});

  @override
  State<Opcion1> createState() => _Opcion1State();
}

class _Opcion1State extends State<Opcion1> {

    dynamic productos; // Variable dinamica para almacenar la respuesta de la API

// Initstate, para cargar primero lo que esta en la función.
   @override
   void initState() {
     super.initState();
     getProductos(); //Funcion futura
   }

// Creación de la función asincrona
   Future<void> getProductos() async {
    
    final response = await Dio().get('urldelAPI');
    productos = response.data; //asignación de los valores

 //Manejo del estado, cuando se obtiene la respuesta manda el cambio de estado
    setState(() {});

   }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Material App',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Pruebas'),
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: Center(
            // Mostramos la respuesta de acuerdo a la estructura de la misma. 
            child: Text( productos?['ocs'][0][2].toString() ?? 'No data'), 
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Lo siguiente es dar formato a la respuesta de acuerdo al diseño y mostrar los datos que requerimos mediante un ListView.

Comment: Only English questions and answers are allowed on SO.